# #MPAndroidChart How to bypass empty data on StackedBar chart

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am a newbie of android developer and it’s 1st post on stackoverflow.
Thanks for your consideration for any inconvenience caused.

I am using MPAndroidChat for StackedBar Chart.
But StackedBar show empty thing on the some position which no entry data. I like to show only 7 data that I provide. Please refer to below screen shoot. It should be show 7 data on 2018/10/12,2018/10/11....2018/10/6, but it show empty chart many times.

Thanks!
Paddy

[detail]

1. The 7 BarEntry data as below
2. And I also follow below issue for timestamp label.
   https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/789

[issue screen shot]

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLdeK.png)

[BarEntry data]
float x=1050,float[] vals={6.0,5.3333335,6.0}

float x=2490,float[] vals={7.3333335,10.0,6.5}

float x=3930,float[] vals={8.5,7.3333335,8.0}

float x=5370,float[] vals={8.333333,7.6666665,7.8333335}

float x=6810,float[] vals={6.6666665,7.6666665,9.5}

float x=8250,float[] vals={8.833333,6.5,8.5}

float x=9690,float[] vals={8.666667,9.0,6.1666665}

Comment: So far I try to workaround by change x is increment by 1 day and use referenceTimestamp and IAxisValueFormatter to correct time by value*24*60*60*1000.

Comment: this.sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

Comment: return sdf.format(referenceTimestamp + value*24*60*60*1000);

Comment: BTW, I ever try to add setGranularity(1f), setGranularityEnabled(true), it could hidden labels, but still show empty chart.

Answer (score 0):

So far I try to workaround by change x is increment by 1 day and use referenceTimestamp and IAxisValueFormatter to correct time by value*24*60*60*1000

## code

```
`this.sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");`
`return sdf.format(referenceTimestamp + value*24*60*60*1000);`
```

BTW, I ever try to add setGranularity(1f), setGranularityEnabled(true), it could hidden labels, but still show empty chart.